# Is there a way to remove record type detail section

Tags: record-type

is there way to remove(through configuration) record type detail section from the record type selection page in new record creation. please refer the attached image.

[image]

Comment: Rather than remove it, add a description to the Recordtypes so that the section becomes more meaningful and the users can tell what they should pick for a given record.

Answer (score 2):

If you always want records to be created with a single record type (say Partner 01), go to Profiles and Update the available record types to only Partner 01. Once only one record type is available, the selection page will not longer be available.

Comment: I need to have multiple record type for users, but need to remove the available record types section as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: That is not possible. If you really need it, you will have to go with a complete custom option by overriding the new button.